# SAS: How to output the last observation in a sequence of a SAS data set

Tags: sas

I want to output the last observation in variable which is an integer sequence in a sas data set.

I have this data set:

```
data have;
input seq var;
datalines;
1 7 
2 6 
3 3 
1 1 
2 4
1 8
2 9
3 1
4 8
;
run;
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
seq var
3   3
2   4 
4   8
```

I have thoroughly searched for my answer online but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a look-ahead technique.  This is one of many ways to write it.

```
data last;
   set have end=eof;
   if not eof then set have(firstobs=2 keep=seq rename=(seq=nseq));
   if nseq eq 1 or eof then output;
   drop nseq;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an indication of the slickness of the look-ahead approach - you can do the same thing with `lag`, but it takes nearly twice as many lines of code:

```
data want(drop=prev_:);
  set have end = eof;
  prev_seq = lag(seq);
  prev_var = lag(var);
  if seq < prev_seq then do;
    seq = prev_seq;
    var = prev_var;
  end;
  if eof or seq = prev_seq;
run;
```